What happens if a successful candidate decides to not take office?
It's November 20th, 2024. A current member of the House of Representatives has resigned his seat with immediate effect. He is no longer a Congressman. His home state will need to follow its procedure for filling vacant House seats to fill out the balance of his current term.
However, he has just successfully run for re-election to the House of Representatives for the next Congress, starting in Jan, 2025. He cannot resign from that position, because he does not hold it yet.
Does he need to appear when the new Congress convenes, be sworn in, and then resign?
Does the person who came second in his election have any part to play in the matter? (S)he is the candidate who has the most votes among those still interested in the job...

If they don't show up to be sworn in, they won't become a Congressman, so they don't have to resign.

The individual sent a letter to the Speaker resigning, and informing him that he does not intend to take the oath for the 119th Congress. But the latter doesn’t matter until that date comes along.

@Damilla  Suddenly a very relevant point...


What happens if a successful candidate decides to not take office?

Federal elective offices
In the case of the United States House of Representatives, if the person elected is never sworn in, then a vacancy arises and the state from which the person was elected must conduct a vacancy election to fill it.
In the case of the United States Senate, state law controls. Some states allow the Governor to fill the vacancy until the next general election. Others allow for an interim appointment until a vacancy election which may be prior to the next general election is held. Others require a vacancy election and do not authorize an interim appointment. Historically, it was once common for Governors to appoint  a spouse or child of a deceased U.S. Senator to fill the vacancy on an interim basis, although this tradition is not a strong as it was historically. Many of the first women in Congress ended up taking office in this manner.
In the case of the Presidency or Vice Presidency, if the candidate drops out or dies prior to the meeting of the Electoral College, the Electors may choose someone else to fill those posts. After the electoral college meets, but before January 20 after the election, the resignation or death of the President-elect causes the Vice President-elect to take office. The resignation or death of the Vice President-elect or the death or failure to quality of the President-elect causing the Vice President-elect to be promoted to President-elect, causes a vacancy to arise in that office which is filled pursuant to the 25th Amendment to the United States Constitution. And, if both offices are vacant, then the Speaker of the House assumes the Presidency in the statutory line of succession, the Vice Presidential vacancy is filled pursuant to the 25th Amendment, and the House seat of the Speaker of the House is filled in a vacancy election.
State elected offices
Some state governments have different systems, although it is conceptually similar, in the sense that the resignation or failure to be sworn in, gives rise to a vacancy that must be filled.
For example, in Colorado, if there is a vacancy in a state legislative office, arising either before the person elected takes office causing that person to fail to be sworn in, or afterwards, a vacancy committee consisting of all elected officials and political party officials of the political party of the person elected convenes to fill the vacancy.
In Colorado, at the local government level, a vacancy in the office of county sheriff is filled by the county coroner, and vacancies in boards and city councils are usually filled with an appointment made by the remaining members of that board. A vacancy in an elected district attorney's office is filled by the Governor.

Does he need to appear when the new Congress convenes, be sworn in,
and then resign?

No.

Does the person who came second in his election have any part to play
in the matter?

No.
